# Reading partition columns without partition column names

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet, partition

We have data stored in s3 partitioned in the following structure:

```
bucket/directory/table/aaaa/bb/cc/dd/
```

where `aaaa` is the year, `bb` is the month, `cc` is the day and `dd` is the hour.

As you can see, there are no partition keys in the path (`year=aaaa`, `month=bb`, `day=cc`, `hour=dd)`.

As a result, when I read the table into Spark, there is no `year`, `month`, `day` or `hour` columns.

Is there anyway I can read the table into Spark and include the partitioned column **without**:

- changing the path names in s3
- iterating over each partition value in a loop and reading each partition one by one into Spark (it is a huge table and this takes far too long and is obviously sub-optimal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark can't [discover partitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery) that aren't encoded as `partition_name=value` in the path so you'll have to create them.

After you load the the paths `bucket/directory/table/aaaa/bb/cc/dd/` into you a DataFrame, you can extract those partitions from the source filename which you get with [`input_file_name()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=functions#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name).

First, split the filename path using `/` delimiter then create columns from the last 4 elements:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn("date_partitions", F.slice(F.split(F.input_file_name(), "/"), -5, 4)) \
    .withColumn("year", F.col("date_partitions").getItem(0)) \
    .withColumn("month", F.col("date_partitions").getItem(1)) \
    .withColumn("day", F.col("date_partitions").getItem(2)) \
    .withColumn("hour", F.col("date_partitions").getItem(3)) \
    .drop("data_partitions")
```

Example:

```
data = [
    (1, 2, "bucket/directory/table/2021/01/10/14/"),
    (3, 4, "bucket/directory/table/2021/01/11/18/")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["a", "b", "input_file_name"])
```

Gives:

```
#+---+---+-------------------------------------+----+-----+---+----+
#|a  |b  |input_file_name                      |year|month|day|hour|
#+---+---+-------------------------------------+----+-----+---+----+
#|1  |2  |bucket/directory/table/2021/01/10/14/|2021|01   |10 |14  |
#|3  |4  |bucket/directory/table/2021/01/11/18/|2021|01   |11 |18  |
#+---+---+-------------------------------------+----+-----+---+----+
```

Comment: So I read the entire table (all partitions) into a df and then create these columns?

Comment: Furthermore, instead of creating separate year, month, day, hour columns, how can I create a single timestamp column from these values?

Comment: I tried this: `.withColumn("timestamp",datetime.datetime(year=int(F.col("data_partitions").getItem(0)), month=int(F.col("data_partitions").getItem(1)), day=int(F.col("data_partitions").getItem(2)), hour=int(F.col("data_partitions").getItem(3))))`

Comment: @KOB Use : `.withColumn("date", F.to_timestamp(F.array_join("date_partitions", "-"), "yyyy-MM-dd-HH")) ` to create date column from the partition parts.