# Spark partitonBy() subdirectory naming

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, partition

I was reading [this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-partitioning-understanding/#:%7E:text=4.2-,partitionBy,-()) article and in section 4.2 it explains how you can use the partitionBy() function to create subdirectories for all values of the column you are trying to partition by. In that example, we see a list of subdirectories in the format "state=some_state_name".

My question is, is there any way to use the partitionBy() function but rename the subdirectories to be "some_state_name", removing the "state=" part?

In other words, how could I modify this code snippet to achieve this naming?

```
df.write.option("header",True) \
        .partitionBy("state") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .csv("/tmp/zipcodes-state")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869626/reading-partition-columns-without-partition-column-names)

"Spark can't discover partitions that aren't encoded as partition_name=value in the path so you'll have to create them."